# launch .json creating error in vscode for java. define the problem .what exactly is going on

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code, launch

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\java practice>  & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2\bin\java.exe' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:57786' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-cp' 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\7e23ce6c36a3d1de7ac32800a3c4efa3\redhat.java\jdt_ws\java practice_d64fcd83\bin' 'loops_2'
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [s\open\src\jdk.jdwp.agent\share\native\libjdwp\debugInit.c:734]
PS C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\java practice>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step to create a **launch.json** file

[image]

[image]